# Google Icon Fonts with Size and Colors don't work?

Tags: icons, material-design, materialize, google-material-icons

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    This is a test page
    <p>
    <i class="material-icons">face</i>
    <i class="large material-icons">face</i>
    <i class="material-icons md-18">face</i>
    <i class="material-icons dark">face</i>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

I see all the icons are same, there is not style applied. Am I doing something wrong or is this not working?

Thanks,Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, I have to use an external CSS, the Google Material Fonts don't have CSS styles

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">

<i class="blue-text text-darken-2 large material-icons ">invert_colors</i>
</p>
```

Thanks, 
Rajesh